# Find field in site collection based on GUID

Tags: powershell, guid

Looking for a way to locate a field by it's GUID in my site collection...any one know a way to do this in powershell and dump out where the field is being used?

Comment: You want to know where the field has been used within the Site Collection?

Comment: yes, so i can find out where it could be located and remove it if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The following should help, I haven't tested it yet..

```
$fieldId = [Guid]"fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247"

$site = Get-SPSite("http://yoursite/") 

foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)  
{            
  foreach($list in $web.Lists)  
  {
    $fieldInUseList = $list.Fields | Where {$_.Id -eq $fieldId }
    if($fieldInUseList) {
        Write-Host "'$web' web - Found a match in the '$fieldInUseList' field in the '$list' list"
    }            
  }
  foreach($ct in $web.ContentTypes) {
     $fieldInUseCt = $ct.FieldLinks | Where {$_.Id -eq $fieldId }
     if($fieldInUseCt) {
        Write-Host "'$web' web - Found a match in the '$fieldInUseCt' field in the '$ct' Contenttype"
     }
  }
}
```

PS: I haven't dispose any of the Webs or Site Collection itself for simplicity..

For removing you can see the below reference:

[PowerShell – Delete field and all references](http://peterheibrink.wordpress.com/2011/12/09/powershell-delete-field-and-all-references/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with REST API, there is a simple way:

```
https://m365x873105.sharepoint.com/sites/<SiteName>/_api/web/lists(guid'GUID OF THE LIST')/fields(guid'GUID OF THE FIELD')
```

Best regards.